# How to get value from XML id - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'd appreciate if someone could help me to solve this issue.

I'm getting this XML by reading a XML file through de code:

```
$x = simplexml_load_file($link);
$g = $x->attributeGroup;
foreach($g->xpath("//PARAMETER") as $attr){
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->ID);
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->VALUE);
    var_dump((string)$attr); // for text value
}
```

I need to get the VALUE inside ID=sitPag, but I'm not able to.

Could anybody help me to do that?

```
<consulta>
<PARAMETER>
<PARAM ID="CodEmp" VALUE="1234"/>
<PARAM ID="Pedido" VALUE="00010714"/>
<PARAM ID="Valor" VALUE="351,20"/>
<PARAM ID="tipPag" VALUE="02"/>
<PARAM ID="sitPag" VALUE="00"/>
<PARAM ID="ValorPago" VALUE="000000351,20"/>
<PARAM ID="dtPag" VALUE="15012020"/>
<PARAM ID="codAut" VALUE=""/>
<PARAM ID="numId" VALUE=""/>
<PARAM ID="compVend" VALUE=""/>
<PARAM ID="tipCart" VALUE=""/>
</PARAMETER>
</consulta>
```

After calling simplexml_load_file(), I'm gettin it:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["PARAMETER"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["PARAM"]=> array(11) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "CodEmp" ["VALUE"]=> string(26) "1234" } } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "Pedido" ["VALUE"]=> string(8) "00010714" } } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(5) "Valor" ["VALUE"]=> string(6) "351,20" } } [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "tipPag" ["VALUE"]=> string(2) "02" } } [4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "sitPag" ["VALUE"]=> string(2) "00" } } [5]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(9) "ValorPago" ["VALUE"]=> string(12) "000000351,20" } } [6]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(5) "dtPag" ["VALUE"]=> string(8) "15012020" } } [7]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "codAut" ["VALUE"]=> string(0) "" } } [8]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(5) "numId" ["VALUE"]=> string(0) "" } } [9]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(8) "compVend" ["VALUE"]=> string(0) "" } } [10]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(7) "tipCart" ["VALUE"]=> string(0) "" } } } } }
```

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: $x = simplexml_load_file($link);
$g = $x->attributeGroup;
foreach($g->xpath("//PARAMETER") as $attr){
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->ID);
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->VALUE);
    var_dump((string)$attr); // for text value
}

Comment: @LucasFusco  Please put your code in the question, not in comments.  Also, don't just say that it doesn't work.  Tell us what _should_ happen, along with what _is_ happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the most efficient (you have to go through each PARAM element until the desired one is found, which could be many), but this will get the job done.

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

foreach($x->PARAMETER->PARAM as $param){

    if((string)$param->attributes()->ID == "sitPag")
    {
        echo (string)$param->attributes()->VALUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/aPYD8)

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath expression to fetch the nodes or values. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` returns an array of SimpleXMLElement instances.

```
$consulta = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$params = $consulta->xpath('PARAMETER/PARAM[@ID="sitPag"]');
$sitPag = isset($params[0]) ? (string)$params[0]['VALUE'] : '';

var_dump($sitPag);
```

In DOM you can use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` to fetch the attribute value directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$sitPag = $xpath->evaluate('string(/consulta/PARAMETER/PARAM[@ID="sitPag"]/@VALUE)');

var_dump($sitPag);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work... My SIMPLE_LOAD_FILE is returnig this way:

Answer (score 0):

In DOM you can use DOMXpath::evaluate() to fetch the attribute value directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$sitPag = $xpath->evaluate('string(/consulta/PARAMETER/PARAM[@ID="sitPag"]/@VALUE)');

var_dump($sitPag);
```

**Or**

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

foreach($x->PARAMETER->PARAM as $param){

    if((string)$param->attributes()->ID == "sitPag")
    {
        echo (string)$param->attributes()->VALUE;
        break;
    }
}
```